# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route" not found

Tags: php, laravel-10

When I add this route:

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
});
```

they show me in web.php this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route"
> not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\store\routes\web.php:16 Stack trace: #0
> {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\store\routes\web.php on line 16